# How can I go from a key 'code' back to its keyboard equivalency?

Tags: keymap, key-bindings

I have the following documentation:

```
mc/keymap is a variable defined in `multiple-cursors-core.el'.
Its value is (keymap
 (67108903 . mc-hide-unmatched-lines-mode)
 (27 keymap
     (118 . mc/cycle-backward))
 (22 . mc/cycle-forward)
 (return . multiple-cursors-mode)
 (7 . mc/keyboard-quit))


Documentation:
Keymap while multiple cursors are active.
Main goal of the keymap is to rebind C-g and <return> to conclude
multiple cursors editing.

[back]
```

I know that `C-g` and `C-v` are `7` and `22`, respectively, but I've no idea what any of the others are.  Is there a function I can use to do this?

```
(equal (??? (kbd x)) x) => t
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`help-key-description` is used to display a humanly-readable key in the documentation when you invoke `describe-key` (<kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>k</kbd>).

```
(help-key-description [22] nil)       ;; --> "C-v"

(help-key-description [67108903] nil) ;; --> "C-'"
```

or

```
(string=
  (help-key-description (kbd "C-g") nil)
  "C-g")
;; --> t
```